# Does Kant anywhere "rationalize" noumena on, say, moral grounds?

Tags: reference-request, kant, new-realism, noumena

I ask in the context of reading various "new realists" or "objective oriented ontologists”. To my reading, many of these thinkers would like to return to Kant's attempt to unify both science and moral freedom, and thereby avoid the path that would lead to German idealism, structuralism, and eventually to supercilious "create your own truth" postmodernism.

I agree with much of this. Kant appears to have feared something like this and kept the idealist balloon tethered to a mind-independent reality in the form of the unknowable noumena. This always struck me as a satisfactory, honest, and fruitfully unstable conclusion.

The point is that to many OOO and "new realist" thinkers it seems this abandonment of "reality" or Kant's noumena by later idealists began the slippery slope into a postmodern moral quagmire. Did Kant himself anywhere argue for the necessity or even "utility" of his *ding-an-sich* on moral or other grounds?

Comment: Postmodernism is quite directly opposed to Hegelianism. There is no Kant - Fichte - ... - Hegel - ... - Heidegger - Derrida line. Heidegger, if he's to be regarded as the root of the newer French philosophy, already flips the German Idealist reading of Kant upside down by emphasizing aspects of Kant's theories that they found the most confused as the most important. Derrida frames his project as a restatement and radicalization of Heidegger's project of destruction of Western ontology (whose most significant representative is Hegel). [1/2]

Comment: Noumenon isn't "mind-independent". It's quite the opposite. Noumenon, as the name itself suggests, denotes a notion of an object which is unconditioned by anything but conditions of thought itself, i.e. is not an object as it appears to our senses, but object as such. This way, if anything, noumenon is what we could totally comprehend because its free of contingency associated with the senses (I think X only according to the notion of X, I sense X according to some contingent circumstances etc.). But Kant says, because thought is without experience empty, noumenon is an empty concept. [2/2]

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA He means Harman (Graham) the "new realist" and most definitely Kant.

Comment: Yes, I'm not familiar with enough of that lineage to connect or refute.Especially Heidegger. I'm looking at an idea from Derrida student Maurizio Ferraris, who, as far as I can tell, connects Kant to structuralism to poststructuralism and then, with a dash of Nietzsche, to Lyotard and a kind of ironic skepticism or relativism (equally good "truths") that has increasingly served right wing political tendencies. Certainly, these connected dots do not go through Hegel.

Comment: Not sure, no expert at all, but can't  noumena be described as a "reality" external to and independent of categorical "constructions" of the mind and its experiences, though I don't know how Kant would put it.

Comment: The noumena are best understood as being the very same things as objects of experience but with all sensory content abstracted. Kant says that all content is sensory, and thought is merely formal, so what remains is quite empty. The idea that we "construct" reality is quite a terrible paraphrase of Kant's position, especially as it encourages reading Kant not through the letter of his work, but through the supposed "spirit". Fichte described his reading in these terms, but he also knew the letter quite well, in contrast with some more recent interpreters who disregard it.

Comment: (I don't mean to criticize you; I just want to point out that this is a common confusion)